# Add To Cart gives two same product instead of one

Tags: addtocart

When I click Add to cart, a lightbox opens with the same product twice.

[image]

[image]

Kindly help.

Comment: What's your magento version?

Comment: Show us Block code?

Comment: Show us phtml code?

Comment: What's your theme?

Comment: try enabling template path hints and check from which file the `pop up is displaying twice` , so in the file you can delete the extra code that is not required......